# Put selected combobox item into label

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, combobox

Hello I am having an error and I can't figure it out. I am trying to select an object in my combobox and display the objects name into a label.

This is my class:

```
class Film
    {
        public string  Naam { get; set; }
        public Film(string naam)
        {
            Naam = naam;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{Naam}";
        }
    }
```

And this is the code of my form

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<Film> filmlijst;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            filmlijst = new List<Film>();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {  
            Film film = new Film(textBox1.Text);

                filmlijst.Add(film);
                comboBox1.DataSource = null;
                comboBox1.DataSource = filmlijst;
        }
        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                label1.Text = ((Film)comboBox1.SelectedItem).Naam;
        }
    }
```

So I create an object of Film with a Textbox to give it a name. 
If I want to add multiple Films my combobox won't reload without this line of code :

```
comboBox1.DataSource = null;
```

Without this line of code I can see the name of my object in the TextLabel. 
But then I can't add more object because it doesn't reload.

Comment: What is your problem? Doesnt seem like the title lines up with what seems to be the issue. Could you clarify your problem?

Comment: Use a BindingList<T> instead.

Comment: Sorry. I want to add multiple objects in my combobox which I create with a textbox to give it a name and press a button to add them into the combobox. Now when I select the object in my combobox I need to get the parameter "Naam" to show up from that object into my Textlabel.  This only works for one object. But if I add another one it crashes because I made my combox.datasrouce empty. But otherwise the form won't update.

Comment: So your question is really about how to update the databinding for a combobox, then, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a [BindingSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource?view=netframework-4.7.2) to let the combo be aware of the changes to your list and when add items add them to the *BindingSource*

First declare the *BindingSource* variable at the class level

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
     BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
     ....
```

Then in the form constructor

```
public Form1()
{
    filmlijst = new List<Film>();
    bs.DataSource = filmlijst;
    comboBox1.DataSource  = bs;
}
```

finally add items to the *BindingSource* and not directly to your list

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        Film film = new Film(textBox1.Text);
        bs.Add(film);
    }
```

This is from the remark section of the docs about the BindingSource

> The BindingSource component serves many purposes. First, it simplifies
>   binding controls on a form to data by providing currency management,
>   change notification, and other services between Windows Forms controls
>   and data sources. This is accomplished by attaching the BindingSource
>   component to your data source using the DataSource property.