# DataGridView.Rows.Insert or DataGridView.Rows.InsertCopy methods don't work

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

**Not able to insert new rows at particular position in DataGridView by using DataGridView.Rows.Insert or DataGridView.Rows.InsertCopy methods.**

**ErrorMessage:** Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound.

```
DataGridViewRow dgwr = new DataGridViewRow();
dgwr.CreateCells(myDataGridView);
myDataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
myDataGridView.AllowUserToDeleteRows = true;
myDataGridView.Rows.Insert(5, dgwr);
```

OR

```
myDataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
myDataGridView.AllowUserToDeleteRows = true;
myDataGridView.Rows.InsertCopy(5, 2);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OACDI.png)

Comment: The message is clear. You have your grid bounded to a datasource. If you want to add something to the grid you need to add to the object used to initialize the grid's datasource. [An example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55290177/put-selected-combobox-item-into-label/55290308#55290308) It is for a combobox but it is the same concept

Comment: See the [DataTable.Merge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.merge) method.